# Is there anyway to prevent "Outlook is using an old .ost file" error?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

So, I have to use Outlook at my work. One of the **most** annoying things is the error

> Outlook is using an old copy of your Outlook data file (.ost). Exit
>   Outlook, delete the file, and restart Outlook. A new file will be
>   automatically created the next time you initiate a send/receive

I don't know why this happens, but this is the 5th time in the past 6 months that it's happened. I know the fix is "delete it and rebuild it". I have a fairly large inbox already though and I'd much rather not having to spend 30 minutes or more downloading email each time this happens. Is there anyway I can prevent this error from occurring? Why does it happen in the first place?

Comment: I would contact your IT Staff for assistance.

Comment: @Ramhound have. They just say to redownload it each time. No one in the (programming) company knows why this happens and everyone just deals with it

Comment: How many emails do you have in your account on the server. Are we talking about hundreds, thousands, tens of thousands?  This honestly sounds like a server side problem causing a client side problem.